# How to add check box value in array if it already coming from DB in php

Tags: php

I have a code which displays Items in check boxes that items are already existing in my DB and the values I have given is also in DB which I need to map it in another page. So how do I push this into an array?
The code is as follow:

```
echo print_chkbx("SELECT * FROM Product_master", database_connect($dbName));
```

and the function is

```
function print_chkbx($query, $link){
    $queried = mysql_query($query, $link);

    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($queried)) {
        $menu .= '
        <input name="check" type="checkbox" value="'. $result['product_id'] .'" />' . $result['product_name'];

    }

    return $menu;
}
```

Comment: do you want the check-boxes to be an array, so when you submit the page they are served as an array?

Comment: Yes @SamuelCook the value of the check box is an array but the name remains the same

Answer (score 0):

This will create a `products` array in the form.

Put `[]` characters after the input name to signify that all inputs with this name are separate entries in an array.

```
$menu .= '
<input name="check" name="products[]" type="checkbox" value="'. $result['product_id'] .'" />' . $result['product_name'];
```

then upon submit they will be served as an array:

```
<?php
$products = $_REQUEST['products']; // used request as unsure of (GET||POST)
echo '<pre>',print_r($products),'</pre>';
```

Comment: Hi @SamuelCook here there are 2 name attrib but I wanted the values to be passed as an array instead of name...

Comment: There is only 1 name attribute that I can see. After submitting the form they will be turned into an array.